# Using Java Spring with Headless/Decoupled CMS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, content-management-system, headless

Currently I am involved in different projects using mainly Java Spring and PHP Laravel. In my work place (ASP.NET based technologies) it is common to use this approach of retrieving the content from the CMS and I could see all the beneficts that it provides so I would like to make something similar but in Java Spring (optionally if it works for Laravel, that would be awesome, but it is just optional).

What I desire:

- A CMS based webpage just to upload the content for different projects in a well organised way.
- The content is going to be mostly "Strings", HTML and pictures.
- From different projects, I am able to connect to the CMS and retrieve this content in the views.
- If it is possible, open source or free solution.

I already searched for different options, but I was not able to find any good solution or some tutorial of how to actualy do it and not just the ideas...

Thank you so much in advance.

Best regards.

Jose Lara.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  It was designed to be paired with Spring Data to allow you to build bespoke headless CMS very quickly and easily.  Moreover, unlike most other CMS's on the market you can choose what component to build it with so you can choose newer cloud-native databases and storage.